# Cannot read property 'rowIndex' of undefined for my javascript code

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
        var cell = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) { 
            cell[i].onclick = function(){alert("Hello world");};
            

            var col = this.cellIndex;
            var row = this.parentNode.rowIndex;

}
    </script>
```

So I have a table, a HTML table. And I am trying to get the column and row of the part of the table that was clicked on, and I am using cell index, and row index. However this is not working and is pulling up the error " cannot read property rowindex of undefined" i couldnt find this error anywhere online..

Comment: `this` is the `window` in code shown. Try it inside the `onclick` function instead

Comment: like this? cells[i].onclick = function(){alert("Hello");};var col = this.cellIndex,row = this.parentNode.rowIndex;

Comment: No..that is not inside the function that you closed with `}` Try using separate lines for your code blocks and closing braces so you can read your code easier

Comment: ohh okay, now I understand. \

Answer (score 1):

As referenced in comments, this will reference the window inside of a for loop, additionally, you're creating your function for alert within the for loop, not something you want to do as this may create weird behaviors. I think what you're trying to achieve will work better with the code below. Tip, unless you need the index you should take advantage of the much simpler "for of" loop.

```js
    function createAlert(td) {
      alert("Hello world")
      var col = this.cellIndex;
      var row = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
      console.log('the col and row:::::', col, row)
    }
    var cell = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    
    for (let td of cell) {
        td.onclick = createAlert
    }
```

```html
<table>
<td>hello</td>
<td>hello2</td>
<td>hell3</td>
<td>hello4</td>
<td>5 hello</td>
<td>hello6</td>
</table>
```